# data range for pvlib forecast modules

Tags: pvlib

I am wondering if it is possible to specify the time range for past data in  GFS, NAM, RAP, HRRR, and the NDFD forecasting models! the current option is recalling data for the present daya as stated here

```
`start = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today(), tz=tz)`
    end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/518cc35567baa15ae203bb8537452927ae10c7a7/pvlib/forecast.py#L242) for the model.get_data() function indicates yes. The only stipulation is that the start and end arguments  must be datetime or timestamp datatypes to be compatible with the netcdf2pandas library